# Desktop Application Authenticate without Client Secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, desktop-application

I don't understand, how you are supposed to keep the client-secret secret in a Desktop application. In [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) they say

> Installed apps are distributed to individual devices, and it is assumed that these apps cannot keep secrets.

But at [Step 5](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code) they do need the secret from the application. How is that supposed to work? I have searched a lot, asked a few Stackoverflow questions to get close and had a good [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/mvyvcg/distributing_desktop_application_which_needs/gvg89kl?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) but the conclusion always was `it should work without a secret but strangely they require the secret`.

I also found [this question from almost 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312000/googles-oauth-2-0-for-installed-apps-and-client-secret-not-being-a-secret). Was there any development on this topic? Or should I just not care and put the secret into the source code?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your desktop application before shipment you will need to compile the client id and client secret into your application as part of a dll or something.  Do not just ship it with the clientsecret.json file.

You could do some fancy encryption on it to encrypt it as part of your application if you want to go overboard.

Google is aware of the fact that someone could decompile your application and get your client id and client secret but this is a gray area as there is no other way around it your application needs the client id and client secret to run and app is installed on the user's machine there for they need to have access to the client id and secret.

Comment: yes I would let my CI compile that into the dll (because my project is open source) but as you said, decompilation is the problem..

Comment: also android and IOS implementations seem to not need the secret and that makes it way weirder

Comment: You cant put it in an open source project.  Your going to have to instruct users how to create their own client id's and verify the application themselves though google.

Comment: This isn't really as big an issue with Android and IOS because the projects are locked to the package name and the SHA-1 fingerprint for Android and the App store Id, bundle id and team id for IOS.    With strictly desktop applications there is no way to link it.

Comment: Yes, I won't put it in an open-source project, the CI can keep secrets, it is going to put the secret into the code when it compiles it so that the source code with the secret can't be found anywhere.

Comment: That's not what I meant. The Google workflow for OAuth seems to not need the secret at all if you are on IOS or Android. The workflow can work without secret anywhere in the app. Why does the Desktop client need the secret then?

Comment: Now your getting into the fun questions: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/225423/146622

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the PKCE flow but I don't know how to do it. As I said, [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) explains it almost perfectly up to [step 5](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code) where you need the secret again sadly.

Comment: Or maybe I understood it wrong. But is there a way to use a public client?

Comment: I thought [that](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) was PKCE